# using sessionAttribute in annotated controller spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/User.html");
@sessionAttributes("user");
class something
```

Now i know that `@Controller =  implements Controller`

```
@requestMaping =   <bean name="/user.html"
```

now i don't know which thing is equal to  `@sessionAttributes("user");` if i don't use annotation

Comment: These things are not equivalent at all, you can't compare like with like.

Comment: by equivalent i mean , they solve one purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SessionAttributes equals a call to `session.setAttribute()` that you would tradionally call in your servlet somewhere to put an object in the session.

Comment: i have seen one example where first project was build without annotation and then same was build with annotation . in annotation he added @session thing but in without annotation example he did not use session.setAttribute. thats why i was confused http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-annotation-controller-1.html And http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-simple-form-controller-1.html

Answer (score 0):

`@SessionAttributes` is different way to declare model object, you can use it like too as `@ModelAttribute` or standard creating new object.